# Prove elementary matrices multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would you prove the following theorem:

Suppose a single ERO is performed on an $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, resulting in a matrix $\mathbf{B}$. If $\mathbf{E}$ is the elementary matrix obtained by performing the same ERO on $\mathbf{I}_m$, then $\mathbf{E}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$.

Like proving why this works and why the order is as it is - for instance, the same cannot be said when elementary matrices are put *after* another matrix, e.g. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{E}$ instead of $\mathbf{E}\mathbf{A}$.

My brain needs to be presented some logic that can explain this.

Comment: Sorry, but what is an ERO ?

Comment: elementary row operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are doing transformations with the rows (i.e, with m-rows of A ), we multiply a matrix ***E*** before A to obtain the matrix B. i,e, ***EA = B***.

Similarly if we do column transformations (i.e, with n-columns of A), we multiply a matrix ***E'*** after A to obtain B',(***AE' = B'***).

Answer (score 0):

$$EA=B\iff A^TE^T=B^T.$$

If you exchange the roles of rows and columns, you must swap the matrices.